# Create HTML Select Options with SQL row values and use these for SQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql

My website contains a form which is used to update or add values to a SQL table. This is the code of the form:

```
<div>

<?php
if (!isset ($sort))
{
    $sort = 'id';
}
if (isset($_GET["sort"])) 
{
$sort = $_GET["sort"];
}
?>                                  

<h3>Add consignment number:</h3>
<form method='post' action='send.php'>

    <div>Order number:</div>
    <div>
    <?php 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ordernumber FROM sentToCustomer");
        echo "<select name='uselection'>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option value='".$row["ordernumber"]."'>".$row["ordernumber"]."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>                      
    </div>

    <div>Consignment number:</div>
    <div><input id='vconsignmentnumber' name='uconsignmentnumber' type='text' value='' required></input></div>
    <div><input name='addSent1Form' type='hidden' value='' /></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"/>

    <div></div>
    <div><input  type='submit'  value="Save"></div>     
</form>
</div>
```

Upon **clicking the save button the page send.php** is being loaded:

```
<?php
include_once("functions.php");

$uconsignmentnumber = $_POST["uconsignmentnumber"];
$uselection = $_POST["uselection"];

SQL_Connect();
$sqlConsignmentNumber = "UPDATE sentToCustomer
        SET consignmentnumber = $uconsignmentnumber
        WHERE ordernumber='$uselection';
        ";
$resultConsignmentNumber = mysql_query($sqlConsignmentNumber);

mysql_close();      
echo "
    <div>
        <fieldset style='margin-top: 40px;'>    
            <legend>Consignmentnumber:</legend>
            <p>
            You just added the Consignment Number ".$consignmentnumber." to the order with the order number ".$uselection.".
            </p>
    </div>
    <div style='float:left;padding-top:3px;'><a href='SentToCustomer.php'<button  value='back'>back</button></a></div>                                      
";
?>
```

**Problem:** The value consignmentnumber isnt written to the database.

I think there might be something wrong with the query on page `send.php`, since its supposed to add **and or** update the consignment number. Both variables `".$consignmentnumber."` and `".$uselection."` are being printed correctly within the "*You just added the Consignment Num*..."-Comment, yet the database INSERT/UPDATE does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: you want to have an fixed value in Select tag then insert/update in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Original :

```
$sqlConsignmentNumber = "UPDATE sentToCustomer
        SET consignmentnumber = $uconsignmentnumber
        WHERE ordernumber='$uselection';
    ";
```

Try this:

```
$sqlConsignmentNumber = "UPDATE sentToCustomer
        SET consignmentnumber = '$uconsignmentnumber' WHERE ordernumber = '$uselection'";
```

Look up  SQL Prepared Statements in php. They will prevent you from being attacked by SQL injection and it is just simpler for making your queries. You basically write(prepare) your query and assign it to a variable and add your parameters to the query afterwards.

Example:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');

$array = array(
    'username' => 'Michael',
    'password' => 'apassword'
);

$query->execute($array);
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. I came up with an idea, which is looking like this:

`$sqlConsignmentNumber = "
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sentToCustomer)
    UPDATE sentToCustomer SET consignmentnumber = $uconsignmentnumber WHERE ordernumber='$uselection'
   ELSE
    INSERT INTO sentToCustomer (ordernumber) VALUES $uconsignmentnumber WHERE ordernumber='$uselection'
   ";`

Unfortunately it does _not_ work aswell